# Django view - switch login_required on and off

Tags: django, django-views, django-permissions

I have a Django application, some view functions have a `@login_required` mixin and permissions to access.

In some site installations, admin want to switch off the login required and permissions for some functions, to make it public.

What is the best way, from site configuration?

Comment: You could write a custom decorator function that checks a flag in your database and requires authenticated users / allows unauthenticated users depending on that flag.

Comment: Yes, I can. But is it some standard way, depend on django-permission lib?